# Dynamic Google Line Charts

Tags: php

I need to draw a line chart using "Google Charts" dynamically from MYSQLI database. I'm fetching the data required for the line chart from the MYSQLI database.

On X-axis, I want weeks and on Y-axis, I want user id's like 0, 200, 400, 600 -----2000.

Here is the code I implemented, Could anyone guide me where I was going wrong.

```
<?php

  $DB_NAME = 'chart'; 
  $DB_HOST = 'localhost'; 
  $DB_USER = 'root';
  $DB_PASS = '';

  $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timemodified),'%d-%m-%Y') AS 'dat', userid FROM user_reg";
  $r = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error()); 
  $transactions = array();

  while($result  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
      $transactions[] = $result;
  } 

  $rows = array();
  $flag = true;
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array( 

    array('label' => 'dat', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'userid', 'type' => 'number') );

  $rows = array();

  foreach($transactions as $tr) 
  {
     $temp = array();
     foreach($tr as $key=>$value)
     {
        $temp[] = array('v' => $value); 
        $temp[] = array('v' => $value);     
     }
     $rows[] = array('c' => $temp); 
  } 

  $table['rows'] = $rows;

  $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
  echo $jsonTable.'<br>';
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
          var options = {
          title: 'Statistics',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't say what the issue/error is that you get, but try avoiding the use of PHP's short tags - they may well be disabled in your version of PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Replace:

```
<?=$jsonTable?>
```

With:

```
<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>
```

Comment: Also, as general comments:

You should always set a password for the default MySQL root user and you should never leave:
or die(etc...)
in production code

Comment: @Nick Roper - I thank you for the comment. Could you tell me as my retrieved data from MySQL is not showing a line in the chart

Comment: Here is the output of the above code - https://www.dropbox.com/s/xp6ck27wp6tep0z/in.png?dl=0